# How can I remove certain chars before the space in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, function

I'm trying without any luck to come up with a method to pass

**Bruno Miguel Alexandre** into **B. Miguel Alexandre**

and

**Bruno Alexandre** into **B. Alexandre**

just in SQL so I can make this part of a big query in a Store Procedure

can anyone provide me with any help? Any function that you guys might already have?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take 1st character + everything from the space. The 8000 is to avoid LEN calls otherwise

```
LEFT(MyValue, 1) + '.' + SUBSTRING(MyValue, CHARINDEX(' ', MyValue), 8000)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try a substring with a CharIndex to find the space

```
with MyTable as
(
            SELECT 'Bruno Miguel Alexandre' as FullName
    UNION   SELECT 'Miguel Bruno Alexandre'
    UNION   SELECT 'Bruno Alexandre'
    UNION   SELECT 'Bruno Miguel'
)
SELECT 
    SubString (FullName, 1, 1) 
    + '.' 
    + SubString (FullName, CHARINDEX (' ', FullName, 1), 8000)
FROM MyTable
```

The output is

```
------------------------
B. Alexandre
B. Miguel
B. Miguel Alexandre
M. Bruno Alexandre

(4 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: y'know, seeing LEN in SUBSTRING irritates me... ;-)